# 'this' is undefined when passing function signature as parameter

Tags: javascript

In the code bellow I'm passing a method of a class instance as callback argument to a another function. But `this` is undefined when I pass just the method signature. So I wonder what changes `this` according to the callback argument format. Is there some JS docs for this specific case?

```
class MyClass {
    foo = 'foo';
    bar() {
        console.log('This is:');
        console.log(this);
    }
}

const handler = (callback) => {
    callback()
}

const myClass = new MyClass()

handler(myClass.bar)
handler(() => myClass.bar())
```

**Output:**

```
This is:
undefined

This is:
MyClass {foo: 'foo'}
```

Comment: `this` is only set when you call a function with the syntax `object.function()`. Just passing `object.function` as a value doesn't bind `this`.

Comment: Arrow functions don't have a `this`

Comment: @RobertRocha - The `this` in question is within `MyClass`'s `bar` method, which does.

Comment: @RobertRocha Statements like this makes little to no sense for js newcomers. Does it mean OP can't use `this` inside an arrow function or what?